# How to change a default table 'users' with another table for Laravel 5.2 registration?

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, registration

I want to use user_detail table to store a register user detail. So, how can I change a default table 'users' with my table for registration in Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Laravel 5.2, all you need to do is to change the [table name in the model code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#defining-models).

This because the Laravel 5.2 auth system uses the model you choose to provide in the `config/auth.php` file. More precisely, in this section:

```
...
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => LaravelSnippets\Entities\User::class,
],
...
```

This counts if you're using Eloquent as driver. Otherwise, if you want to use the database driver, you will also need to specify the table. You'll find an example on the `config/auth.php` file.